# Mocking APi calls jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I have a DataService which is responsible for my API calls - I am trying to mock the api call in jest but it does not seem to be working.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong - my DataService seems to be undefined.

Here is the function

```
const getStepData = (id) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch(fetchStepBegin());

      const res = await DataService.fetchStepData(id);
      const sortedTask = sortedTaskData(res)

      const sortedStepData = sortStepData(res)
      const newData = createSortedDataForDragAndDrop(sortedTask, sortedStepData)
      dispatch(fetchRawStepDataSuccess(res.data))
      dispatch(fetchStepDataSuccess(newData))
    }
    catch (err) {
      dispatch(fetchStepError(err))
      throw (err)
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the test that I have written - I am pretty sure I am mocking incorrectly

```
  it('Data Api end point called with corrent studyId', () => {
    jest.mock(DataService);
    DataService.fetchStepData() = jest.fn()
    CellStepManagementOperations.getStepData(5);
    expect(DataService.fetchStepData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(5);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are trying to test **asynchronous** action creators, **synchronously**. So your `expect` function doesn't wait for your `getStepData` to finish before running.

I've had to something very similar to what you're trying to do and I used a library called [redux-testkit](https://github.com/wix/redux-testkit). Please see the part about testing async action creators with services [here](https://github.com/wix/redux-testkit#recipe---unit-testing-thunks). You can even set mock return values for your API services which I've found very helpful when testing.

Using this library, you will be able to `await` for your `getStepData` async action creator to complete before running your `expect` function.

You will have to play around with your code but it might look something like this:

```
it('Data Api end point called with corrent studyId', () => {
  jest.mock(DataService);
  DataService.fetchStepData() = jest.fn()
  const dispatches = await Thunk(CellStepManagementOperations.getStepData).execute(5);
  expect(DataService.fetchStepData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(5);
});
```